# Почему изменяется РАЗРЕШЕНИЕ ИЗОБРАЖЕНИЙ на странице КАТЕГОРИИ в Opencart 3

Tags: php, javascript, cms, opencart, изображения

Почему к изображению автоматически добавляется расширение 360х360. И за этого появляются белые полосы по бокам. Пожалуйста подскажите как от этого избавится.
Как сделать что бы картинка занимала весь блок?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**img src**

```
<div class="image"><a  href="{{ product.href }}"><img src="{{ product.thumb }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" title="{{ product.name }}" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>


    'thumb'=> $image,

$image = $this->model_tool_image->resize($result['image'], $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_width'), $this->config->get('theme_' . $this->config->get('config_theme') . '_image_product_height'));
```

Answer (score 0):

**РЕШЕНО**

Оказывается расширения можно изменять прямо в админке)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]